# QGIS - Extract by location, what does Cross do?

Tags: qgis, select-by-location

I don't understand what Cross does when extracting by location, and how it differs from Overlap- the definition on the [user guide](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#extract-by-location) is very confusing - it says:

> **Cross**: Returns 1 (true) if the supplied geometries have some, but not all, interior points in common and the actual crossing is of a
>   lower dimension than the highest supplied geometry. For example, a
>   line crossing a polygon will cross as a line (selected). Two lines
>   crossing will cross as a point (selected). Two polygons cross as a
>   polygon (not selected).

Can someone explain this in a clearer way, maybe with a simple example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand it this way:

> **Overlap** - Tests whether a geometry overlaps another. Returns 1 (true) if the geometries share space, are of the same dimension, but
>   are not completely contained by each other. Only circle 2 is selected.

*Share space* in this case is meant for polygon. Overlapping polygons share some **spce/area** so it is used for extracting/selecting polygons.

> **Cross** - Returns 1 (true) if the supplied geometries have some, but not all, interior points in common and the actual crossing is of a
>   lower dimension than the highest supplied geometry. For example, a
>   line crossing a polygon will cross as a line (selected). Two lines
>   crossing will cross as a point (selected). Two polygons cross as a
>   polygon (not selected).

*Crossing polygon* or *two line crossing* - this is meant for lines. Cross is used for extracting/selecting lines which crosses any segment of target polygon layer (or line layer), since line with polygon (or other line) can't share any **space/area**.

Comment: That makes perfect sense, thank you!